# Monitoring software for Windows 11 + Docker server

Tags: windows, server, ssh, docker

I've setup a test server at my home for learning purposes using a computer with Windows 11, Docker working with WSL2 and configuring my router to forward certain ports to that computer.

It works flawlessly, but I'm wondering how can I manage it remotely.

Is there any monitoring software that allows me to:

1. Monitor the system resources
2. Restart the computer
3. Manage Docker containers (optional)

Currently I'm using the Windows 11 built-in SSH server, but it would be better to have a responsive user interface to manage it through my phone. Work with commands in mobile phones is cumbersome.